# ORDER BY a scalar subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT * FROM Teest ORDER BY 1;  -- OK if you're using PostgreSQL
SELECT * FROM Teest ORDER BY 'error, of course';
ERROR:  non-integer constant in ORDER BY
```

So I wonder whether I can use a *scalar subquery* in `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Teest ORDER BY (SELECT 1);
```

However, it turns out that **the `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` doesn't take effect** (i.e., the results are NOT sorted).
It doesn't throw an error either.

Why?  Isn't it an integer?
**But PostgreSQL doesn't throw an error if I write `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)`; this indicates that PostgreSQL knows that `ORDER BY` is followed by an integer.**  (Otherwise, it will give an error message as shown above.)

---

To create the table `Teest`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Teest (_ INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Teest VALUES (1), (3), (5), (2), (4), (6);
```

PostgreSQL v16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer in the `ORDER BY` clause [has a special meaning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each `expression` can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (`SELECT` list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values.

That is why it is treated different from a string constant. The error alerts you that sorting by a constant makes no sense whatsoever. If you say `ORDER BY 1`, that does not mean "sort by a constant" (a no-operation), but "sort by the first column".

The SQL-92 standard allows only column aliases and integers in the `ORDER BY` clause. PostgreSQL extends that by allowing almost arbitrary expressions. The subquery `(SELECT 1)` is not flattened, so PostgreSQL doesn't know it is really an integer constant.

Comment: And more recent versions of the SQL standard don't allow order by ordinal position, but order by (more or less) arbitrary expression.

Comment: @jarlh I'd have to verify that. But PostgreSQL wouldn't break compatibility by changing that.

Comment: I assume all dbms's still support it.

Comment: @jarlh I looked in the 2003 and 2013 standard, and it looks like you are right.

Comment: "*The subquery `(SELECT 1)` is not flattened, so PostgreSQL doesn't know it is really an integer constant.*" May I ask what that sentence means? PostgreSQL doesn't throw an error, so I think it knows that this is an integer.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. Can you cut out the second paragraph? This has nothing to do with the actual question; it just repeats what I already know.

Comment: Quod scripsi, scripsi.